# How to compute the Alexander polynomial of general torus knot

Tags: knot-theory, gr.group-theory

Hello,

i am very interested in knot theory, especially in knot groups and knot polynomials. Therefore i am reading the book of Crowell and Fox (Introduction to knot theory). I want to compute some Alexanderpolynomials (with the technique they use in this book, thus Fox calculu, Abelization, free groups etc.) I can do this for special knots for example trefoil and cinquefoil (this are also exercises in this book). But now i want to compute the Alexanderpolynomial of the torus knot $T_{p,q}$ for $p$ and $q$ coprime. Therefore they want to prove that the following formula holds:
$$\Delta(T_{p,q})=\frac{(t^{pq}-1)(t-1)}{(t^p-1)(t^q-1)}$$
if the knot group is $G(T_{p,q})= \langle  x,y:x^p=y^q\rangle$ (this is not so difficult to prove). But here i can give the solution (or the way to solve it -.-). I have also make computations but they they are not good. Can someone help me with this? Thank you for help :)

Comment: Have you looked at Rolfsen's book "Knots and Links"?

Comment: Crossposted to math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381319/alexanderpolynomial-of-torus-knot  

Answer (score 7):

This is an exercise in many topology books. Here is a reference with a complete
proof: Look up Example 9.15 in the book "Knots" by G. Burde and H. Zieschang.
The Jacobian of the presentation $G(T_{p,q})=\langle x,y \mid x^py^{-q}\rangle$
is computed. It is
$$
\left( \frac{t^{pq}-1}{t^q-1}, -\frac{t^{pq}-1}{t^p-1}\right).
$$
The greatest common divisor of it is the Alexander polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the computation of the Alexander polynomial of  torus knots and  more general algebraic knots goes back to Bureau. There is a general trick called the *Seifert-Torres* formula that allows you to compute the desired Alexander polynomial  of the $(p,q)$-torus knot and much more.  For a particularly an elegant proof based on the concept of Reidemeister torsion  I refer to Turaev's most excellent survey [*Reidemeister torsion in knot theory*](http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/41/1/R03/pdf/0036-0279_41_1_R03.pdf), Russian Math. Surveys, vol. 41 (1986), 119-182. The concept of Reidemeister torsion  is what hides behind the Alexander polynomial so it's worth having a look at this concept.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I found another link for it, where you do not need a subscription: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/turaev1.pdf 
